# MySql - How to get average data from two tables?

Tags: mysql

**Products Sold Table**

Holds records of every single item purchased as an order can have many products.

```
+----+------------+---------+----------+-------+
| ID | PAYMENT_ID | PROD_ID | STORE_ID | PRICE |
+----+------------+---------+----------+-------+
|  1 |          1 |       5 |        4 | 3.00  |
|  2 |          1 |       4 |        4 | 4.00  |
|  3 |          2 |       3 |        7 | 5.00  |
|  4 |          3 |       8 |        9 | 10.00 |
+----+------------+---------+----------+-------+
```

**Payment Table**

Keeps records of the payment for the order.

```
+----+-------+------------+----------+
| ID | TOTAL |    DATE    | STORE_ID |
+----+-------+------------+----------+
|  1 | 7.00  | 10/10/2010 |        4 |
|  2 | 5.00  | 01/07/2011 |        7 |
|  3 | 10.00 | 20/02/2012 |        9 |
+----+-------+------------+----------+
```

How can I create query or a function that would give me how many sales were made every month (Jan to Dec) on average in the years 2010/2011/2012 for a given store.

For example, if “Store 4” sold 5 products in January in 2010, in 2011 and in 2012 then the average sales for that store in the month of January would be 5.

I tried:

```
SELECT storeid, paymentdate 
FROM payment_table 
WHERE (YEAR(paymentdate)=2010 OR YEAR(paymentdate)=2011 OR YEAR(paymentdate)=2012) 
    AND (storeid=1)
```

This doesnt do much apart from get the dates of all the payments for a given store.

Comment: @stephen.vakil `SELECT storeid, paymentdate FROM payment_table
WHERE (YEAR(paymentdate)=2010 OR YEAR(paymentdate)=2011 OR YEAR(paymentdate)=2012) 
AND (storeid=1)` This doesnt do much apart from get the dates of all the payments for a given store.

Comment: Join the tables, then use `COUNT(*)` and `GROUP BY YEAR(Date), MONTH(Date)` to get the counts for each month. Put that into a subquery, and use `AVG(count)` and `GROUP BY month`

Comment: To add to @Barmar 's comment you also need to use STR_TO_DATE or DATE_FORMAT functions to format your dd/mm/yyyy format so it can be used by YEAR and MONTH functions.

Comment: Why do you have `store_id` in both `products_sold` and `payment`? Can the product be sold from a different store than the one in the payment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to join the tables to get the sales counts for each time period. Put that in a subquery so you can regroup it by month.

```
SELECT month, AVG(sales) AS avg_sales
FROM (SELECT MONTH(paymentdate) AS month, YEAR(paymentdate) AS year, COUNT(*) AS sales
      FROM payment_table AS pay
      JOIN products_sold_table AS prod ON pay.id = prod.payment_id AND pay.store_id = prod.store_id
      WHERE YEAR(paymentdate) IN (2010, 2011, 2012) AND pay.store_id = 1
      GROUP BY month, year
) AS x
GROUP BY month
```

Comment: Could you please edit answer so that it returns the data for a given store which I specify as there is more than one store. And I see that you have `COUNT(*) AS sales`; how can this be replaced with the sum of products sold rather than the sum of its price.

Comment: It's not the sum of its prices, it's just the count of rows in the joined tables.

Comment: Sum of prices would be `SUM(price)`